# OpenWhisk error: "The action did not return a dictionary" for NodeJS code

Tags: node.js, openwhisk

I have Vagrant VM for OpenWhisk running on Windows 10.  I have written the following code for writing a record to MongoDB.

```
function entryPoint(args) {

  var coindata = {name:args.coindata.name,price: args.coindata.price}

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
     var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var returnMessage;

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mongoose.connect("mongodb://192.168.16.1:27017/angularcrud").then(
        () => 
        {
          var Coin = new Schema({ 
            name: {
              type: String
            },
            price: {
              type: Number
            }
          });


          var coinModel = mongoose.model('Coin', Coin);
          var coinObj = new coinModel(coindata);


          coinObj.save()
          .then(item => {
            resolve("Data Saved");;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            reject(err);
          });

        },
        err => { return reject(err)}
        ); 

    })
  }

 module.exports.main = entryPoint;
```

I have executed the following command:

```
wsk action -i invoke testing -br -p coindata "{\"name\": \"coin200\", \"price\": 3 }"
```

after the execution of the above command, I see that the record is getting added to the MongoDb, but at the same time I also see the following error on the console.

```
{
    "error": "The action did not return a dictionary."
}
```

I have gone through two threads in stackoverflow related to this error. Both the threads talk about returning 'promise', which I have written in the code. I have no idea what else should I do

Answer (score 2):

OpenWhisk requires a return value that is a valid dictionary. The value that you resolve/reject on is the value that is returned to OpenWhisk when the function completes. Therefore the value you resolve/reject on needs to be a valid dictionary. In other words, since you are using javascript, the value you should be resolving on is a valid JSON object whereas you are currently resolving on a string which is not a dictionary/JSON object. What you would like to do is

`resolve({'result': "Data Saved"});`

or maybe

`resolve({'Data': 'Saved!'})`

ultimately OpenWhisk requires a dictionary/hashmap/JSON object/thesaurus or any other structured key value mapping returned explicitly as JSON

Comment: I updated the code to return "resolve({'result': "Data Saved"});". Now, when I execute the action, I see nothing being returned. No error message, but the record is saved. This is Okay for me as long as there are no errors, but why is it not showing any message now on the console. ?

Comment: how are you invoking the action?

Comment: do you get an activation id?

Comment: try `wsk action invoke testing -br ` , this tells OpenWhisk to block while running your action and then it tells it to return the result object once the action completes

Comment: if that doesn't provide you with the expected result, can you then just execute that function from within the node environment just to ensure the code is sound?

Comment: I am executing the action with command λ wsk action -i invoke addcoin -br -p coindata "{\"name\": \"coin200\", \"price\": 3 }". I do nto get any activation ID, because nothign is returned. If I execute this code on NodeJS, it works fine, i.e, I can type the message to the console.